# JSP scriptlet inside JS for loop

Tags: javascript, jsp

I'm practicing Dynamic Web Project using Model2. I find that when I use JSP scriptlet inside JavaScript's for loop. **The scriptlet <%...%> only runs once**. 
I thought it should run as many time as JS for loop does. How could that happened?  And what should I do to solve it?

**Focal Point:**

```
<script language='javascript'>
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    for(i=1;i<=<%=arrLen%>;i++)
    {
        var row = table.insertRow(i-1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell1.innerHTML = <%=i%>;
        cell2.innerHTML = <%=list.get(i)%>;
        <% i=i+1; 
        System.out.println("i="+i);%>
    }
</script>
```

---

**Details:**

## JSP

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%@ page import="   java.util.List,
                    java.util.ArrayList" %>
    <div>
        <h1>Result</h1>
        <table id="myTable"></table>
        <br>
    </div>
    <p>There are <%=request.getAttribute("result_number") %> results.</p>

<%
    int arrLen = (int)request.getAttribute("result_number"); 
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=arrLen;i++)
    {
        list.add((String)request.getAttribute("result"+i));
        System.out.println("Test list:"+list.get(i-1));
    }
    i=1;
%>

<script language='javascript'>
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    for(i=1;i<=<%=arrLen%>;i++)
    {
        var row = table.insertRow(i-1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell1.innerHTML = <%=i%>;
        cell2.innerHTML = <%=list.get(i)%>;
        <% i=i+1; 
        System.out.println("i="+i);%>
    }
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

---

## Result Page

[image]

---

## Console

Test list:COLD
Test list:123
Test list:321
Test list:222
Test list:123123
Test list:123
Test list:123
Test list:1111111111111
Test list:123
i=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i got the answer why it only run once.
It's because JSP is run on back end and JavaScript is run on front end.
So that when your web container transform it to servlet.
This original jsp may like this.

```
cell1.innerHTML = <%=i%>;
cell2.innerHTML = <%=list.get(i)%>;
```

But the servlet will generate a html like this

```
cell1.innerHTML = 1;
cell2.innerHTML = 123;
```

That's why i got the result like that.

So the code should be rewrite to:

```
<script language='javascript'>
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var bound =<%=arrLen%>; 
    <%
    for(int j=0; j<list.size(); j++)
    {
        %>
        var row = table.insertRow(<%=j%>);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell1.innerHTML = '<%=j+1%>';
        cell2.innerHTML = '<%=list.get(j)%>';
        <%
    }
    %>
</script>
```